# i cant move the camera with gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

i have given the player tag to gameobject still the code is not working in unity..its a flappy bird game.

```
public class CameraTracks : MonoBehaviour {

    Transform player;
    float offsetx;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameObject player_go=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        if (player_go == null) {
            Debug.LogError("could not find game object with tag player");
            return;
        }
        player =player_go.transform;
        offsetx = transform.position.x - player.position.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (player != null) {
            Vector3 pos=transform.position;
            pos.x = player.position.x + offsetx;
            transform.position=pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the values you're getting/setting in the `Update()` loop, to make sure they're all as expected? It could help narrow down the problem a bit.

Comment: the game is working on another computer i just copied the file..but this function is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should attach this script to the camera which you want to track the player, since the global `transform` refers to the object's transfrom attached to the script.

Comment: i have attached it but still not moving with game object